# Background image for Safari on Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, safari

On my iPhone I can add a custom image for new tabs in Safari.

How do I accomplish the same thing for Safari on my Mac? I have tried plugins (like Momentum) but I don't want to have to pay for such a basic feature.

Comment: I have 15.3 -- where can I find this?

Comment: Sorry, Safari has this only for the start page. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: See https://9to5mac.com/2020/09/14/how-to-customize-safari-14-start-screen-with-wallpapers-on-macos/